# cmake found different paths for BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I using this to fount BOOST:

```
set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
find_package( Boost 1.52 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED )
message(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Cmake find the **BOOST 1.52** library I installed in a separate folder, but it links with the system **BOOST 1.41** libraries located in `/usr`:

**BOOST_ROOT** is set but cmake only use it for INCLUDEs, not LIBs. Cmake debug output for BOOST.

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:347 ] Boost not in cache
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:350 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:352 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:354 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:412 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:414 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:416 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:418 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:420 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:469 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:471 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0/include;/gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:473 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:497 ] location of version.hpp: /gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:516 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.52.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:602 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:612 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:628 ] _boost_STATIC_TAG = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:630 ] _boost_ABI_TAG = d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:659 ] _boost_LIBRARIES_SEARCH_DIRS = /gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0/lib;/gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0/stage/lib;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/boost/boost_1_52_0/lib;/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:788 ] Boost_FOUND = TRUE
-- Boost version: 1.52.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
```

Comment: Did you remove CMakeCache when updated boost? Try to clear directory with build files and run cmake again. Also show your TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES content

Comment: I clear it with rm -rf * in build folder

Comment: My target_link_libraries is: 

    target_link_libraries(machen ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(machen ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Comment: try to set Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS to true then clean up folder and re-run cmake

Comment: What is in `/gpfs/res_apps/BOOST/1.52.0/lib`? Are the required libraries actually there?

Comment: if it doesn't help try to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the location with new libs

Comment: @ixSci, I tried setting Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS to true, but it doesn't solve. But I tried also setting Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED to false, and now it works

Comment: Did you try to set add the `EXACT` keyword to your `find_package` call?

Comment: @JohannesS. The EXACT keyword only affect the version, but it should work with several version.

Comment: This is an old thread, but it came up towards the top on Google, so I'm adding what has worked for me onto the pile.  I've had good luck with adding -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE to my command lines.  This is along with having BOOST_ROOT set as well as making sure that Boost is built with threading=true because sometimes CMake insists on finding the -mt libraries.